# (ag-Grid)How to put the background color to multiple selected rows

Tags: angular, ag-grid

How is it able to put background color to multiple selected row in ag-Grid.

[image]

It functioned in the example of [tutorial](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/#gsc.tab=0) , but can't figure out how even if I examine the code in Plunker....

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ty01OdEIUP1IL5oFZw8z?p=preview)

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the `ag-row-selected` class, this class is applied to all selected rows.